# How do I get words from a file line by line and seperated by a semicolon in C++?

Tags: c++, file

I have the code written below. I am trying to build a dictionary from German to English. I have all the words on a text file seperated by a semicolon (around 100 lines), the first part of the line is the German word, and after the semicolon comes the English translation ("Hund; Dog"). How do I take the first word and store it in a varable, ignore the semicolon, and then store the second word in a seperate variable?

```
ifstream myfile("tiere_animals.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        Entry Animal[661];

        while (getline(myfile, line, ';'))
        {
            line2.push_back(';');
            line2.clear();
            line3.append();

        }
        myfile.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

> How do I take the first word and store it in a varable, ignore the semicolon, and then store the second word in a seperate variable?

Just read up until a `;`, then read up until a newline.

```
std::string english, german;
while (std::getline(myfile, german, ';') && std::getline(myfile, english, '\n')) {
       std::cout << german << " in english is: " << english << "\n";
}
```

Comment: With added benefit of avoiding regex usage.

Comment: @TanveerBadar *avoiding \*anything\*'s usage* is not always a benefit. It always depends on the task. In this case regex adds reasonable flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::regex`:

```
#include <regex>
#include <streambuf>
#include <fstream>

using German = std::string;
using English = std::string;

std::vector<std::pair<German, English>> ParseFile(const std::string& filename)
{
   std::fstream f{filename, std::fstream::in};
   if (!f.is_open())
       throw std::exception("failed to open the file");
   // given you said that there are no motre than 100 lines, you can read the whole file at once
   std::string fileContent{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(f),
                           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};

   std::regex pat{R"((?:(\w+);\s(\w+)\n))"}; \\ suppose you have a format like "German; English(end of line)"

   std::regex_iterator start{fileContent.cbegin(),
                             fileContent.cend()},
                       end{};

   std::vector<std::pair<German, English>> out;

   while (start != end)
   {
      const std::smatch& sm = *start;
      // may check here if subgroups mathced.
      out.emplace_back(sm[1], sm[2]); // sm[0] is a main group.       
      ++start;
   }

   return out;
}
```

But you need your file to be properly formatted.

---

For those, who don't like STL regex: in this particular case there are no stated limitations regarding memory usage or time-efficiency.
Besides that, `std::regex` introduces extensibility, since you do not need to change your code rather than a pattern. So, you would easily apply your parsing algorithm to files with another layout;

```
// can be used as a functor
class Parser
{
   std::regex pattern_;

   public:
   Parser(std::regex pattern)
      : pattern_(pattern)
   {}


   static std::vector<std::pair<German, English>> Parse(const std::string& filepath); // see above;

   operator std::vector<std::pair<German, English>>(const std::string& filepath) const
   {
       return Parse(filepath);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole line first, then separate its words:

```cpp
ifstream myfile("tiere_animals.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    string line, german, english;
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        getline(iss, german, ';');
        getline(iss >> ws, english);
        ...
    }
    myfile.close();
```